# AlarmManager set method not working when called from boot receiver

Tags: android

I have looked everywhere for this solution most of the replies ask to set alarm in boot receiver.

i have implemented a boot receiver and started a service and set a alarm using set method.

Service is started fine but alarm is not setting.

please help i am stuck on that.

i can post some also if you want but boot receiver is working fine as i am also starting service in that

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPref = context.getSharedPreferences(
            Util.SHARED_PREF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    long curTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long endTime = sharedPref.getLong(Util.END_TIME, -1);
    long startTime = sharedPref.getLong(Util.START_TIME, -1);

    if (curTime < endTime && startTime >= curTime) {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, HUD.class);
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 1987,
                intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, endTime, 100, pintent);
        Log.e("alaram set", endTime + " " + curTime);
    }

    Intent service = new Intent(context, HUD.class);
    context.startService(service);
}
}
```

MyReceiver.java

```
 <receiver
        android:name=".MyReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Manifest.xml

Service started successfully after boot

but `alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, endTime, 100, pintent);`

alarm is not working.

I think i clear my question.

Plz help

Comment: plz help i am stuck on that

Comment: Developer community plz help i am stuck on that, i searched everywhere  i checked my code several times. but somehow its not working :(

Comment: what will be your end time here

Comment: It looks like problem in your end time

Comment: i debug several times even i removed if condition,its not working

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, HUD.class);
PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 1987,
            intent1, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30);
alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                cal.getTimeInMillis(), 100, pending);
```

Try your `setInexactRepeating` instead of `setRepeating` that is more performance optimized method.

Comment: its working if i set alarm alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, endTime, 100, pintent); byt this method only thing that is not working if this code execute in boot receiver.